# How to apply nested navigation in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

**What I use:**

Kotlin, Jetpack Compose

**What I want to do:**

After clicking "Log In" text I would want to navigate user to the log in form

**What I currently have:**

*MainActivity.kt*

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val viewModel: MainActivityViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        installSplashScreen().apply {
            setKeepOnScreenCondition {
                viewModel.isLoading.value
            }
        }
        setContent {
            RestaurantioTheme {
                Surface(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    val navController = rememberNavController()
                    Scaffold(
                        content = {padding ->
                            Column(
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(padding)
                            ) {
                                Navigation(navController = navController)
                            }
                        },
                        bottomBar = {
                            BottomNavigationBar(
                                items = listOf(
                                    BottomNavItem(
                                        name = "Home",
                                        route = "home",
                                        icon = Icons.Outlined.Home
                                    ),
                                    BottomNavItem(
                                        name = "Orders",
                                        route = "orders",
                                        icon = Icons.Outlined.ShoppingBag
                                    ),
                                    BottomNavItem(
                                        name = "Map",
                                        route = "map",
                                        icon = Icons.Outlined.Map
                                    ),
                                    BottomNavItem(
                                        name = "Profile",
                                        route = "profile",
                                        icon = Icons.Outlined.Person
                                    ),


                                ),

                                navController = navController,
                                onItemClick = {
                                    navController.navigate(it.route) {
                                        popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                                            saveState = true
                                        }
                                        launchSingleTop = true
                                        restoreState = true
                                    }
                                }
                            )

                        }
                    )

               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*BottomNav.kt*

```
@Composable
fun Navigation (navController: NavHostController) {

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "home" ) {

        composable("home") {
            HomeScreen()
        }

        composable("orders") {
            OrdersScreen()
        }

        composable("map") {
            MapScreen()
        }

        composable("profile") {
            ProfileScreen()
        }

        composable("login") {
            MapScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

**What I've tried:**

Inside my ProfileScreen() Composable I have

```
        ClickableText(
            AnnotatedString("Log In"),
            onClick = {

            })
```

But I can't navigate to login screen. I've tried something like this:

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
        Navigation(navController)
        ClickableText(
            AnnotatedString("Log In"),
            onClick = {
                navController.navigate("login")
            })
```

but it doesn't work as intended, because I have HomeScreen(start screen) on top of my ProfileScreen, and after clicking LogIn text I have this "temporary" MapScreen.

I know that I'm doing something wrong, but I've just started learning compose and I can't really understand navigation documentation for nested navigation, which as I suppose should be used here.

If it helps, below is the beginning of ProfileScreen Composable, maybe I have to pass some argument there.

```
@Composable
fun ProfileScreen(viewModel: AuthenticationViewModel = androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel()) {
...
}
```

[image: Image from Application]

Answer (score 1):

You can add a function as parameter to ProfileScreen and use this function for the onClick event.

```
ProfileScreen(goToLogin: () -> Unit){ 
  ...

  ClickableText(
     AnnotatedString("Log In"),
     onClick = goToLogin
  )
}
```

In your Navigation composable you can add the function to the ProfileScreen composable like this

```
val goToLogin = remember{{ navController.navigate("login") }}
composable("profile") {
     ProfileScreen(goToLogin = goToLogin)
}
```